UNZIP from a folder in a zip file to the current path?
I want to install Wordpress on mysite.com/blog
I download wordpress-6.6.1.zip from the official site and upload it to the "blog" folder at mysite.com
When I unzip the file I see that inside wordpress-6.6.1.zip there is a folder named "wordpress" and now wordpress is at mysite.com/blog/wordpress and I don't want that.
I search the net to find if it's possible to unzip all the content from the "wordpress" folder, including sub-folders to the current path, and see that it cannot be done with one command. There is no option that can do that. (I know how to overcome this. It's not the issue here.)
Does this feature exist but I didn't find it?
If it doesn't exists, why?
Am I the only person in the world who has this need?
Was it suggested and rejected? For what reasons?
Thanks,
Hanan Cohen

Does mv wordpress/* . && rmdir wordpress provide a solution? Perhaps the option was not implemented since the "problem" is so easy to overcome.

unzip can’t do this, but other archive tools capable of extracting .zip files can. For example, with bsdtar:
bsdtar -x -f wordpress-6.6.1.zip --strip-components 1

This extracts the archive, removing the first component from all paths in the file (the wordpress directory).
